# How to SELECT data other than the selected MONTH and YEAR in Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

**Query**

```
where item_name like 'Laptop%' and month(pr_date) != 09 and YEAR(pr_date) != 2016
```

I want to display data other than month 09 and 2016, how can i do that

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:

```
where item_name like 'Laptop%' and
      (pr.date < '2016-09-01' or
       pr.date >= '2016-10-01'
      )
```

Or:

```
where item_name like 'Laptop%' and
      not (pr.date >= '2016-09-01' and pr.date < '2016-10-01')
```

Direct date comparisons are highly recommended -- when possible -- over using functions such as `year()`.  Direct comparisons help the optimizer choose the best execution plan.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking for both values combined, and then apply NOT so records that match the combination are filtered out:

```
where item_name like 'Laptop%'
and   NOT (month(pr_date) = 09 and YEAR(pr_date) = 2016)
```

Note that this may not be efficient when querying: if an index exists on the column, the index will not be used because functions are applied on the column.

Answer (score 0):

Actually question is not soo clear.

1. May you wanted to output just all years without months September and not 2016 permanently. If so:

   `select item_name, pr_date from your_table  where item_name like 'Laptop%'  and   NOT (YEAR(pr_date) = 2016 and month(pr_date) = 09)`
2. May you wanted all data just not 2016 September. If so:

   `select item_name, pr_date from your_table where item_name like 'Laptop%' and not (pr.date >= '2016-09-01' and pr.date < '2016-10-01')`

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the most efficient but it works.

```sql
where item_name like 'Laptop%' and concat(month(pr_date), YEAR(pr_date)) != '92016'
```

Note the leading `0` from `09` might get trimmed.